# Pi Zero W goes black screen while running pyqt qml app

Tags: pi-zero-w, qt, raspberry-pi-desktop

I wrote a pyqt5 app that uses QQmlApplicationEngine to load a qml file for the GUI. Now everything runs well on my PC and also on Raspberry Pi4b, but when I am trying to run it on Pi Zero W, it loads the GUI and then partially or fully goes black.

I can use ssh and also checked the task manager to see whether it's throttling the pi or not. But it does not look like an issue. and everything else works.

I am running the official 32-bit pi os.

I get this kind of error on the terminal when running the app. But it also appears on rpi 4.

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 191, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138522/xcb-error-148-qt-application-display-issues

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for your comment. I read through the answer there. The solution was to use static linking while cross-compiling for qt with C++. But I think static linking ain't an option for pyqt5. The cross-compiling setup does not work for pi zero because it is arm v6 (I guess).

Comment: After reading the article, my guess is this "XCB error" is the real issue. Another correction is that this does not appear on RPI4. Last time what I did after installing the fresh OS, the apt update and upgrade commands were executed on RPI4 and then I plugged the SD card into the PI zero. This time i will do these on PI zero directly. I will update on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue in the future:

Just hook up a HDMI display, it solves the problem instantly! I was working headless and the error only comes with the headless mode.